# Add Content to DIV with Specific Class Name

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to alter Wordpress `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>` default output. What I wish to do:

Pages that have a submenu looks like this:

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a href="#">Page with Submenu</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Level 1 Submenu Page</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Submenu Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

What I need it to look like:

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a href="#">Page with Submenu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Level 1 Submenu Page <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Submenu Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Any ideea on how can I achieve this by CSS, jQuery or PHP?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Nothing at the moment. No idea where to start so I can use the best method.

Comment: I would start with a google search for 'customize wordpress menu'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding the extra markup just to add a down arrow, why not do this with CSS:

```
.menu-item-has-children > a {
    padding-right:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    content:"";
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:50%;
}
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmx9jut2/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: you'll need PHP. Then some CSS styling.

To be more specific, you'll need to use a [Custom Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function). With a custom walker, you can tell WordPress to use different styling for a menu, then another style for a sub-menu and so on, which is your exact case. You even have an example code there, which I'm pasting below:

```
class themeslug_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

// add classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'sub-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}

// add main/sub classes to li's and links
 function start_el(  &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
        $args->before,
        $attributes,
        $args->link_before,
        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
        $args->link_after,
        $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

it looks you know some coding, so I won't extend on this, but it's easy to see you only need to modify this:

```
$classes = array(
        'sub-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
```

and/ or

```
// depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
```

according to your needs. However, **I STRONGLY RECOMMEND** you read the page so you understand how it works, how you use it and when to use it.